# R: How can I find all the classes in a package

Tags: r, class, architecture, package

I am trying to design the class structure for my first package, and want to look at some models of S3 classes written in R by experienced R programmers. Is there a method of listing all the classes in a given package (possibly including the base package) and, for each, any parent classes to which it belongs?

Comment: `library(data.table); showClass("data.table")`

Comment: Have you looked at Hadley's [OO field guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html)? Keep in mind an S3 "class" is just string set in a attribute. There are no proper S3 classes like in other languages. There's no central repository of classes. There isn't really a parent class, so much as a list of classes an object can act like.